# creating a function for processing my dataframe calculations

Tags: r, dataframe, analysis

I am doing systematic calculations for my created dataframe. I have the code for the calculations but I would like to:

1) Wite it as a function and calling it for the dataframe I created.

2) reset the calculations for next ID in the dataframe.

I would appreciate your help and advice on this.

The dataframe is created in R using the following code:

```
#Create a dataframe
dosetimes <- c(0,6,12,18)

df <- data.frame("ID"=1,"TIME"=sort(unique(c(seq(0,30,1),dosetimes))),"AMT"=0,"A1"=NA,"WT"=NA)
doserows <- subset(df, TIME%in%dosetimes)

doserows$AMT[doserows$TIME==dosetimes[1]] <- 100 
doserows$AMT[doserows$TIME==dosetimes[2]] <- 100
doserows$AMT[doserows$TIME==dosetimes[3]] <- 100
doserows$AMT[doserows$TIME==dosetimes[4]] <- 100

#Add back dose information
df <- rbind(df,doserows)
df <- df[order(df$TIME,-df$AMT),]       
df <- subset(df, (TIME==0 & AMT==0)==F)

df$A1[(df$TIME==0)] <- df$AMT[(df$TIME ==0)]


#Time-dependent covariate
df$WT <- 70                    
df$WT[df$TIME >= 12] <- 120  

#The calculations are done in a for-loop. Here is the code for it:
#values needed for the calculation
C <- 2     
V  <- 10    
k <- C/V

#I would like this part to be written as a function

for(i in 2:nrow(df))
{

t <- df$TIME[i]-df$TIME[i-1]
A1last <- df$A1[i-1]

df$A1[i] = df$AMT[i]+ A1last*exp(-t*k)
}

head(df)

plot(A1~TIME, data=df, type="b", col="blue", ylim=c(0,150))
```

The other thing is that the previous code assumes the subject ID=1 for all time points. If subject ID=2 when the WT (weight) changes to 120. How can I reset the calculations and make it automated for all subject IDs in the dataframe? In this case the original dataframe  would be like this:

```
#code:
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
dosetimes <- c(0,6,12,18)
df <- data.frame("ID"=1,"TIME"=sort(unique(c(seq(0,30,1),dosetimes))),"AMT"=0,"A1"=NA,"WT"=NA)
doserows <- subset(df, TIME%in%dosetimes)
doserows$AMT[doserows$TIME==dosetimes[1]] <- 100 
doserows$AMT[doserows$TIME==dosetimes[2]] <- 100
doserows$AMT[doserows$TIME==dosetimes[3]] <- 100
doserows$AMT[doserows$TIME==dosetimes[4]] <- 100
df <- rbind(df,doserows)
df <- df[order(df$TIME,-df$AMT),]       
df <- subset(df, (TIME==0 & AMT==0)==F)
df$A1[(df$TIME==0)] <- df$AMT[(df$TIME ==0)]
df$WT <- 70                    
df$WT[df$TIME >= 12] <- 120 
df$ID[(df$WT>=120)==T] <- 2
df$TIME[df$ID==2] <- c(seq(0,20,1))
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: So which part of this don't you actually know how do to? Where is the actual programming question? Right now it seems like this is just a "please do this for me" request.

Comment: 1. I would like to write the for-loop as a function so I can call it for dataframes; like df2 <- calculate.func (df).

Comment: 2: I don't know how to reset the calculations for the next subject ID. (i.e. do the same calculations again for ID=2 starting from TIME=0 for ID2) @MrFlick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, when doing calculations on different subject's data, I like to split the dataframe by ID, pass the vector of individual subject data into a for loop, do all the calculations, build a vector containing all the newly calculated data and then collapse the resultant and return the dataframe with all the numbers you want. This allows for a lot of control over what you do for each subject

```
subjects = split(df, df$ID)
forResults = vector("list", length=length(subjects))

# initialize these constants
C <- 2     
V  <- 10    
k <- C/V

myFunc = function(data, resultsArray){
  for(k in seq_along(subjects)){
    df = subjects[[k]]
    df$A1 = 100 # I assume this should be 100 for t=0 for each subject?

    # you could vectorize this nested for loop..
    for(i in 2:nrow(df)) {

      t <- df$TIME[i]-df$TIME[i-1]
      A1last <- df$A1[i-1]

      df$A1[i] = df$AMT[i]+ A1last*exp(-t*k)
    }

    head(df)

    # you can add all sorts of other calculations you want to do on each subject's data

    # when you're done doing calculations, put the resultant into 
    # the resultsArray and we'll rebuild the dataframe with all the new variables
    resultsArray[[k]] = df

    # if you're not using RStudio, then you want to use dev.new() to instantiate a new plot canvas
    # dev.new()   # dont need this if you're using RStudio (which doesnt allow multiple plots open)
    plot(A1~TIME, data=df, type="b", col="blue", ylim=c(0,150))

  }

  # collapse the results vector into a dataframe
  resultsDF = do.call(rbind, resultsArray)
  return(resultsDF)
}

results = myFunc(subjects, forResults)
```

Comment: Thank you @skotturi . I tested it, it is actually doing the wrong calculations. It appears that my question my question wasn't clear enough. I posted a new question again which is more clearer of what i want to achieve. I would be grateful if you could have a look at it. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25908142/how-to-write-the-for-loop-into-a-function-how-to-apply-it-by-subject-id)

Comment: Looks like you received an answer that works for you. I should point out that the answer for that question does the same thing this answer does, it splits the data by subject, runs all the calculations you want (you seem to have added a couple variables), and then puts the whole dataframe back together. There's a fancy package for doing this called plyr, although when people are learning R I generally recommend writing it all out by hand manually as it's easier to see what's going on (instead of doing an unsplit(lappply(split(data,func))). They all work, just depends what helps you learn best.

Comment: Thank you for your help and guidance. You are absolutely right; writing the code manually and understanding it helps a lot. To be honest, I always have hard times understanding the (apply) family functions. I am learning a bit more day after day =)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this:

```
ddf <- data.frame("ID"=1,"TIME"=sort(unique(c(seq(0,30,1),dosetimes))),"AMT"=0,"A1"=NA,"WT"=NA)

myfn = function(df){

    dosetimes <- c(0,6,12,18)
    doserows <- subset(df, TIME%in%dosetimes)

    doserows$AMT[doserows$TIME==dosetimes[1]] <- 100 
    doserows$AMT[doserows$TIME==dosetimes[2]] <- 100
    doserows$AMT[doserows$TIME==dosetimes[3]] <- 100
    doserows$AMT[doserows$TIME==dosetimes[4]] <- 100

    #Add back dose information
    df <- rbind(df,doserows)
    df <- df[order(df$TIME,-df$AMT),]       
    df <- subset(df, (TIME==0 & AMT==0)==F)

    df$A1[(df$TIME==0)] <- df$AMT[(df$TIME ==0)]


    #Time-dependent covariate
    df$WT <- 70                    
    df$WT[df$TIME >= 12] <- 120  

    #The calculations are done in a for-loop. Here is the code for it:
    #values needed for the calculation
    C <- 2     
    V  <- 10    
    k <- C/V

    #I would like this part to be written as a function

    for(i in 2:nrow(df))
    {

    t <- df$TIME[i]-df$TIME[i-1]
    A1last <- df$A1[i-1]

    df$A1[i] = df$AMT[i]+ A1last*exp(-t*k)
    }

    head(df)

    plot(A1~TIME, data=df, type="b", col="blue", ylim=c(0,150))

}

myfn(ddf)
```

For multiple calls:

```
for(i in 1:N) {
    myfn(ddf[ddf$ID==i,])
    readline(prompt="Press <Enter> to continue...") 
}
```